# How to pin Cell on select in Tableview?

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I would like the selected cell to be pinned to the Tableview top and stay there while scrolling like section header when .plain style is used but for cell.

I don't know how to approach the problem. I know that the code should be placed at `didSelectRowAt`.

Comment: by default when you select a cell it's not going to deselect 'till you call deselect function , can you explain more please .

Comment: ok I changed the post

Answer (score 0):

If your tableView cells are static, and you want the selected cell to be displayed at the top, You should try:

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
     let selectedRow = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! yourTableViewCell // this wont apply if your cells are static 
     let firstVisibleIndexPath = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows.first
     tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: firstVisibleIndexPath)
}
```